# can't clone from windows git to wsl

Tags: git, wsl-2, github-desktop

I'm using github desktop with wsl-2.
after some update of git & github desktop, when trying to clone a repo using git or github desktop I get "permissions denied",
here are "censored" logs from github desktop:

```
2022-03-02T13:44:00.579Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/my_company/my_repo.git - username (has token)
2022-03-02T13:44:00.682Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= -c protocol.version=2 -c init.defaultBranch=master clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/my_company/my_repo.git \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\my_repo` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
stderr:
fatal: could not create work tree dir '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\my_repo': Permission denied

(The error was parsed as 21: Permission denied.)
```

other git operations work, only this one doesn't.
I ran chmod 777 on the relevant folder it did not help.
please help, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install the [latest GCM v2.0.692](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.692), this should be resolved with [PR 612](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/pull/612):

> ### Update IsWslPath to detect `\\wsl.localhost`-style paths
>
> Starting in [Windows build 21354](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-21354), the preferred WSL UNC file path is `\\wsl.localhost\<distro>\` and not the older administrative-share style `\\wsl$\<distro>\`.
>
> The older "`wsl$`" style will continue to be supported, but won't be the default type of path we'll see from the system going forwards.
>
> We now support detecting both styles as WSL paths.